# Taiwanese looking PHP error message

Tags: php

There was a PHP error message I came across a while ago. It looked Taiwanese, all capital letters, two words. I can't remember how I got the error message which is why I cant find it again but I was talking to someone about it and need to reference it. Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean the [scope resolution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) "paamayim nekudotayim"?

The error was probably "[`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paamayim_Nekudotayim#PHP)"

Comment: Good catch. I'd have expected some East-asian script characters, not latinized Hebrew :)

Comment: Phwww. How you can guest that. Incredible.